# If $A$ is a self-adjoint operator . Is $\|A^n\|=\|A\|^n,\;\forall n$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $E$ be an infinite-dimensional complex Hilbert space.

> Let $A\in \mathcal{L}(E)$ be a self-adjoint operator i.e. $A^*=A$, is
>   $$\|A^n\|=\|A\|^n,\;\forall n\in \mathbb{N}?$$

Note that if $A$ is self-adjoint, then
$$\|A\|=\sup\left\{|\langle Ax, x\rangle|\,;\;x\in E,\;\|x\|= 1\right\}.$$

It is well known that if $T\in \mathcal{L}(E)$, then
$$\|T^*T\|=\|T\|^2.$$
So since $A$ is self-adjoint, then
$$\|A^2\|=\|A\|^2.$$
I try to show the result by induction.

Comment: It is a corollary of the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Multiplication_operator_version)

Comment: Diagonalize and see I suppose

Comment: But $E$ is an infinite dimentional Hilbert space

Comment: Do we know that $A^n$ (or just $A^2$) is also self-adjoint ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas $A^n$ for all $n$.

Comment: @Student By the way, for the finite case, you can use this result https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2657175/prove-that-phi2-lambda-where-lambda-is-the-largest-eigenvalue-of-th to prove the above theorem easily.

Comment: More generally, this is true for normal operators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is known that [all elements in the spectrum of a selfadjoint operator are approximate eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/384947/22857). So there exists a sequence $\{x_j\}$ with $\|x_j\|=1$ for all $j$ and $Ax_j-\|A\|\,x_j\to0$.

Now we proceed by induction on $n$. If $A^nx_j-\|A\|^nx_j\to0$, then 
$$
A^{n+1}x_j-\|A\|^{n+1}x_j=A(A^nx_j-\|A\|^nx_j)+\|A\|^n(Ax_j-\|A\|x_j)\to0.
$$
It follows that, for each $n$, $A^nx_n-\|A^n\|x_j\to0$. This implies that $A^n-\|A\|^nI$ is not invertible, that is $\|A\|^n\in\sigma(A^n)$. But then
$$
\|A\|^n\leq\|A^n\|,
$$
which is the non-trivial inequality. Thus, $\|A^n\|=\|A\|^n$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 2):

The spectral radius theorem tells you that for any self-adjoint operator 
$$
 \lVert A \rVert = \sup_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)} \lvert \lambda \rvert,
$$
where $\sigma(A)$ denotes the spectrum of $A$. Using that $f(\sigma(A)) = \sigma(f(A))$ for any continuous function $f$ on $\sigma(A)$, you get the desired result.