# Formula for the least element on the spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $A$ be a self-adjoint operator defined on a dense subset of an Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Assume that $A$ is bounded below in the sense there is $m \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\langle Ax,x\rangle \geq m,~\forall x : \|x\| = 1.$$

I want to show that:
$$ m = \inf\{\lambda : \lambda \in \sigma(A)\} = \inf \{\langle Ax,x\rangle : \|x\| = 1\}.$$

I know that if $E_A$ denotes the unique spectral measure that represents $A$, then $\mathrm{supp}~E_A = \sigma(A),$ from which follows the first equality. So, it is only left to prove the last equality. Any hints?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $m=\inf\;\{ \lambda : \lambda\in\sigma(A) \}$. Then, for every positive integer $n$, $E_{A}[m,m+1/n] \ne 0$. So there exists a unit vector $x_n\in\mathcal{D}(A)$ such that $E_{A}[m,m+1/n]x_n = x_n$, which gives
\begin{align}
   0 & \le \langle (A-mI)x_n,x_n\rangle \\
     & = \int_{m}^{m+1/n}(\lambda-m) d\langle E(\lambda)x_n,x_n\rangle \\
     & \le \frac{1}{n}\langle E[m,m+1/n]x_n,x_n\rangle \\
     & \le \frac{1}{n}\langle x_n,x_n\rangle = \frac{1}{n}.
\end{align}

Therefore, $\lim_n \langle A x_n,x_n\rangle = m$.

Comment: Just one question, why does $E_A[m,m+1/n]\neq 0$ imply that there is $x_n$ such that $E_A[m,m+1/n]x_n=x_n?$

Comment: @L.F.Cavenaghi If $x_n=E_A[m,m+1/n]x \ne 0$, then $E_A[m,m+1/n]x_n = x_n$ because $E^2(S)=E(S)$.

Comment: thank you very much! So simple!

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts This might be obvious but just double checking (I am new to this stuff). From the above argument is it correct to conclude that the kernel of $A-mI$ is not empty, $A-mI$ is not an injection and so $m\in\sigma(A)$? so $m$ is actually the minimum of the spectrum.

Comment: @RozaTh : $m$ could be an eigenvalue; or it could be an approximate eigenvalue only, in which case $A-mI$ would have null space equal to $\{0\}$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Thank. I guess, I am little confused then. How can we argue that $m$ is an approximate eigenvalue? Here we only have $\langle (A-mI)x_n,x_n\rangle$ goes to 0, but we need $\|(A-mI)x_n\|$ to go to zero.

Comment: @RozaTh : You know that $E[m,m+1/n] \ne 0$ for all $n > 0$. If $E\{m\}\ne 0$, then $m$ is an eigenvalue; otherwise, if it is $0$, then $E(m,m+1/n]\ne 0$ for all $n$, which makes $m$ and approximate eigenvalue.

Answer (score 2):

For a selfadjoint operator, every element of the spectrum is an [approximate eigenvalue](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/384947/22857). That shows your equality.

Comment: nice comment. Thank you! +1