# Spectrum and Convergence of an operator

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, weak-convergence, strong-convergence

can you help me to solve this exercice? The first point is ok but I have problems with the others.
Let $S_\varepsilon$ an continuous operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ define as $$ S_\varepsilon[f](x)= \sin(\frac{x}{\varepsilon}) f(x) $$

i) show that is self-adjoint;
[Solution. Simple: $(S^*_\varepsilon[g],f)=(g,S_\varepsilon[f])=(S_\varepsilon[g],f)$, and the symmetry of $(,)_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}$]

ii) Find the spectrum (point, residual, compression)

iii) show that $||S_{\varepsilon}[f](x)||\nrightarrow 0$

iv) show that $||S_{\varepsilon}[f](x)||\rightharpoonup0$

Comment: What have you tried for parts (ii), (iii), (iv)? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A selfadjoint operator [has no residual spectrum](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/383684/22857). Let us write $h=\sin x/\varepsilon$, as the argument is the same for any choice of function. If $\lambda$ were an eigenvalue, you would have $\lambda f = hf$, or 
$$
(\lambda - h) f=0
$$
(all equalities are "a.e."). So you need $f=0$ wherever $\lambda-h\ne0$. As the sets of zeroes of $h-\lambda$ has measure zero, you get that $f=0$ a.e. So $S$ has no eigenvalues, and so the whole spectrum belongs to the pure approximate point part.

Using the same idea it is easy to see that the spectrum of $S$ is the (essential) range of $h$. In this case $h$ is continuous so it is the actual range: $$\sigma(S_\varepsilon)=[-1,1].$$

For the norm convergence, take $$f=\tfrac{n}{\sqrt2}\,1_{I_n},\ \ \ \text{ where } \ I_n=\left(\tfrac1n\left(\tfrac\pi2-\tfrac1n\right),\tfrac1n\left(\tfrac\pi2+\tfrac1n\right)\right).
$$
Then $\|f\|=1$ and 
$$
\|S_{1/n}f\|^2=\frac{n}{\sqrt2}\int_{I_n}\sin^2{nx}\,dx\geq\sin\left(\tfrac\pi2-\tfrac1n\right).
$$
Thus $\|S_{1/n}\|\to1$, making it impossible for $\|S_\varepsilon\|\to0$.

Item $iv$ as written makes no sense. I assume it means $S_\varepsilon f\to0$ weakly. Assume first that $f=1_{[-k,k]}$, $g=1_{[-m,m]}$, with $c=\min\{m,k\}$. Then

$$
|\langle S_\varepsilon f,g\rangle|=\left|\int_{-c}^c
\sin\tfrac x\varepsilon\, dx\right|
=\varepsilon\left|\int_{-c/\varepsilon}^{c\varepsilon}\sin v\,dv \right|
=2\varepsilon|\cos \varepsilon c|\leq2\varepsilon\to0.
$$
Since steps functions are linear combination of $f$ or $g$ as above, we get 
$\langle S_\varepsilon f,g\rangle\to0$ for all $f,g$ step functons. Now for arbitrary $f,g$ we may approximate by step functions (the step functions are dense, since they approximate the continuous functions with compact support, and these are dense in $L^2(\mathbb R)$) and still show that $\langle S_\varepsilon f,g\rangle\to0$.

Comment: Thank you, I don't understand why the sets of zeroes of $h−\lambda$ has measure zero. Can you explain this? PS item iv) is as you say, I was wrong to write !

Comment: That part's not true in general, but it is for your $h$. If $h$ is constant on a set of positive measure, then the multiplication operator will have an eigenvalue.

Comment: You say "Since every simple function is a linear combination of $f$ or $g$ as above..." but don't you get step functions and not simple functions in this fashion?

Comment: You are right. But step functions are dense in $L^2(\mathbb R)$: because the step functions are dense in the continuous functions with compact support, and this in turn are dense in $L^2(\mathbb R)$.